# Получаю сообщение Call to abstract method at address при попытке запуска отладки проекта weblaz 1.0

Tags: lazarus

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
    SysUtils, Classes, httpdefs, fpHTTP, fpWeb, cthreads;

type

 { TFPWebModule1 }

 TFPWebModule1 = class(TFPWebModule)
  procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure DataModuleRequest(Sender: TObject; ARequest: TRequest;
  AResponse: TResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  private

  public

  end;

  var
    FPWebModule1: TFPWebModule1;

  implementation

  {$R *.lfm}

   { TFPWebModule1 }



   procedure TFPWebModule1.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin

   end;

   procedure TFPWebModule1.DataModuleRequest(Sender: TObject; ARequest: TRequest;
      AResponse: TResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
   begin

   AResponse.Content := ARequest.Command;
     Handled := true;

    end;

   initialization
       RegisterHTTPModule('TFPWebModule1', TFPWebModule1);
   end.
```

Работаю с плагином weblaz. При запуске этого шаблона получаю сообщение:

> "Call to abstract method at address..."

Lazarus 2.2.0. Ubuntu.
В чём причина?